# Stream- and future builder not getting built

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter

So before the `futurebuilder` and the `streambuilder` used to work,but I `listbuilder` in the `streambuilder`,so I decidec to change it,and now its not working, I put prints in `futurebuilder` and `streambuilder`,but they are not getting printed,nothing is happening..

I'm not getting any error. I'm 100% sure that the queries are correct.

Here is the whole code:

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
 import 'package:rezervisanje/globals.dart' as globals;
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class ReserveTable extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
   _ReserveTableState createState() => _ReserveTableState();
}

class _ReserveTableState extends State<ReserveTable> 
{
  var sum;
  var step = 0;
  var hours = 0;
  var minutes = 0;
  DateTime times;
  final List<LoadList> terminlist = new List();
  final List<LoadList> items = new List();
  final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  Future<int> firebaseQuery;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    firebaseQuery = Firestore.instance
        .collection('salons')
        .document(globals.salonkey)
        .get()
        .then((document) {
      setState(() {
        globals.shiftstart = document.data['firstshiftstart'];
        globals.shiftend = document.data['firstshiftend'];
      });
    });
  }

   @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (globals.day == null) {
      globals.day = DateTime(
          DateTime.now().year, DateTime.now().month, DateTime.now().day);
    }
    times = globals.day.add(new Duration(days: -1));
    new FutureBuilder(
      future: firebaseQuery,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          print("snapErr");//not getting printed
          return new Text("${snapshot.error}");
        } else
          items.clear();
        print("SHIFTEND " + globals.shiftend.toString());//not getting printed
      },
    );
new StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
    stream: Firestore.instance
        .collection('termins')
        .where('time', isLessThanOrEqualTo: globals.day)
        .where('time', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: times)
        .where('employeeID', isEqualTo: globals.employeeID)
        .snapshots(),
    builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
      print("2");//not getting printed
      if (!snapshot.hasData)
        return const Text('Connecting...');
      else {
        print('3');//not getting printed
        sum = snapshot.data.documents.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < sum; i++) {
          DocumentSnapshot items = snapshot.data.documents[i];
          DateTime date = items['time'];
          terminlist.add(new LoadList(date.hour, date.minute));
        }
      }
    });

int div =
    ((globals.shiftend - globals.shiftstart) * 60 / globals.requiredtime)
        .round();
hours = globals.shiftstart;
for (var i = 0; i < div; i++) {
  if (minutes == 60) {
    minutes = 0;
    hours = hours + 1;
  }
  items.add(new LoadList(hours, minutes));
  minutes += globals.requiredtime;
}

return new Scaffold(
    appBar: new AppBar(
      title:
          new Text(globals.employee == "" ? "Reserve" : globals.employee),
      backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrange,
    ),
    drawer: new Drawer(
        child: new ListView(children: <Widget>[
      new ListTile(
          title: new Text("Close"),
          trailing: new Icon(Icons.arrow_upward),
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
          })
    ])),
    body: Card(
        child: Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Form(
          key: formKey,
          child: new ListView.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              itemCount: items.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                print(sum);//only this is getting printed,its null
              })),
    )));
 }
}

class LoadList {
 final hours;
 final minutes;
 LoadList(this.hours, this.minutes);
}
```

I was searching the problem for hours.What should I change?
Thanks!

Comment: I'm a bit confused, you create a FutureBuilder/Streambuilder, but then return a Scaffold that doesn't use them ? So once you return the Scaffold as part of the build method, what happens to the Builders that aren't used? I'm not sure if they would be killed or not ? That feels wrong, but it could be me who is wrong also :).

Comment: I don't know why I did that, Futurebuilder is good as it is. I wanted to use the streambuilder to read the data and put in a list,and to refresh when a data is added,tell me what would you do,ill try it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the way I use them together:

```
class _PostListState extends State<PostList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<PostParams>(
      stream: PostBloc().param,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<PostParams> params) {
        if (params.hasError) {
          return new Center(child: Text(Api.StreamError));
        } else {
          return new FutureBuilder(
            future: Post.get(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
              switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                case ConnectionState.none:
                case ConnectionState.waiting:
                  return new Center(child: new CircularProgressIndicator());
                default:
                  if (snapshot.hasError)
                    return new Center(child: Text(Api.FutureError));
                  else {
                    return new ListBuilder(snapshot.data);
                  }
              }
            },
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

This way **StreamBuilder** is responsible for handling the parameters coming from UI and **FutureBuilder** calls the API and act when the result is back.

You don't need the StreamBuilder if you don't have some States changed in a Stream.

Comment: Okay this works,but its now refreshing when I add a date to firebase,how would be that possible?

Comment: I think that calling the Post.get() inside the FutureBuilder everytime the widget refreshes the get() it's called again even if the future is resolved, being that every changes triggers the StreamBuilder that return again the FutureBuilder.

Comment: @FrancescoMineo is right. The way this is implemented causes the new get every time the StreamBuilder's stream is changed. If this is not the thing you need, probably there is no need to have the StreamBuilder.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted,I just messing with some logical errors...
Would you take a look at it?